# Properties of automorphism group of $G={Z_5}\times Z_{25}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G={\Bbb Z}_5\times {\Bbb Z}_{25}$. What is the order of $Aut(G)$ and is $Aut(G)$ abelian?

---

I don't know if this has anything to do with the result
$$
Aut({\Bbb Z}_n)\cong U(n).
$$

Does one have to count $Aut(G)$ by "brute force"? I've seen two similar questions:

- [number of automorphism on $\mathbb{Z}_9\times \mathbb{Z}_{16}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/173985/9464)
- [Order of the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb Z_{15} \times\mathbb Z_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/459775/9464)

But I don't see how this can be reduces to those two cases. I think that whether $Aut(G)$ is abelian can be partially told from its order.

Comment: What is $U(n)?$

Answer (score 6):

For abelian groups $G,H,K$ we have natural isomorphisms
$$\hom(G,H \times K) \cong \hom(G,H) \times \hom(G,K),$$
$$\hom(G \times H,K) \cong \hom(G,K) \times \hom(H,K).$$
This enables you to compute $\hom(G,H)$ for arbitrary finite abelian groups $G,H$, as soon as you know that $\hom(\mathbb{Z}/n,\mathbb{Z}/m) \cong \mathbb{Z}/\mathrm{gcd}(n,m)$. It also follows that $\mathrm{End}(G)$ can be represented as a certain matrix ring, and $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a group of invertible matrices. For the general procedure and all details, see

> Christopher J. Hillar, Darren Rhea, *Automorphisms of finite Abelian groups*, [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605185)

For example, if $p$ is a prime, then
$$\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{Z}/p \times \mathbb{Z}/p^2) \cong \begin{pmatrix} \hom(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}/p) & \hom(\mathbb{Z}/p^2,\mathbb{Z}/p) \\ \hom(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}/p^2) & \hom(\mathbb{Z}/p^2,\mathbb{Z}/p^2) \end{pmatrix} \cong \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{Z}/p & \mathbb{Z}/p \\ \mathbb{Z}/p & \mathbb{Z}/p^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Do you have a reference for the result in the first line?