# A question about the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I wanted to clarify some confusion I was having on the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4}$, which I call $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4})$.

I considered the following as a presentation of this group $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4} = \langle r,s : r^{2}=1=s^{4}, sr=rs \rangle$. Looking at this presentation, an element $\alpha \in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4})$ will send $r$ to $r$ or $s^{2}r$ and will send $s$ to $s, s^{3}, sr$, or $s^{3}r$.

Using this, I was able to list $8$ possible automorphisms. I did not check this carefully, but the autmorphisms that I listed each had order $2$ and I may not be remembering this correctly but a group of order $8$ where all the non-identity  elements are of order $2$ is abelian.

I turned to looking at $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{25})$ where I found this question:

[Properties of automorphism group of $G={Z_5}\times Z_{25}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633995/properties-of-automorphism-group-of-g-z-5-times-z-25)

The answer uses the following proposition the result of which is found in the paper below(which I haven't finished reading yet to verify):

> Christopher J. Hillar, Darren Rhea, *Automorphisms of finite Abelian groups*, [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605185)

For example, if $p$ is a prime, then
$$\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{Z}/p \times \mathbb{Z}/p^2) \cong \begin{pmatrix} \hom(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}/p) & \hom(\mathbb{Z}/p^2,\mathbb{Z}/p) \\ \hom(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}/p^2) & \hom(\mathbb{Z}/p^2,\mathbb{Z}/p^2) \end{pmatrix} \cong \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{Z}/p & \mathbb{Z}/p \\ \mathbb{Z}/p & \mathbb{Z}/p^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

But I think based on that result, my conclusion that $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4})$ is abelian looks to be false.

**I am essentially wondering if I did something wrong**

Comment: $r\mapsto sr$ can't be happen in an automorphism, since $sr$ is not of order $2$. Maybe you meant $r\mapsto s^2r$.

Comment: Endomorphisms are not the same as automorphisms, BTW. You'd have to figure out which of those are invertible.

Comment: The automorphism $r \mapsto rs^2$, $s \mapsto rs$ has order $4$, not $2$, and the full automorphism group is nonabelian and isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $8$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, I made the correction

Comment: @DerekHolt I think, you pointed me to my mistake. I thank you with great enthusiasm.

Comment: @DerekHolt Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered by a comment:

> The automorphism $r↦rs^2$, $s↦rs$ has order 4, not 2, and the full automorphism group is nonabelian and isomorphic to the dihedral group of order 8. – Derek Holt Dec 21 '14 at 22:39

Also helpful:

> Endomorphisms are not the same as automorphisms, BTW. You'd have to figure out which of those are invertible. – Thomas Andrews Dec 21 '14 at 22:18