# What is group isomorphic to $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_8)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is group isomorphic to $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_8)$?
I don't even know order of this group.
Please give me hint or proof outline.

Thanks!

Comment: You can explore this group with [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org). Construct it with `g:=AutomorphismGroup(DirectProduct(CyclicGroup(4),CyclicGroup(8)));`. Now `Size(g)` returns 128 and `StructureDescription(g)` returns `"(C2 x (((C4 x C2) : C2) : C2)) : C2"` where `:` denotes a semidirect product.

Comment: Solution goes like in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077053/a-question-about-the-automorphism-group-of-mathbbz-2-times-mathbbz-4?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Let $m\neq n$, and $p$ be a prime. Then  order of the group ${\rm Aut}(Z_{p^m} \times Z_{p^n})$ is given by
$$
\phi(p^m)\phi(p^n)p^{2\min(m,n)}.
$$
This has been shown at MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27200/number-of-automorphisms-of-a-direct-product-of-two-cyclic-p-groups). In our case we have $p=2$ and $(m,n)=(2,3)$, so that the order is $128$. This coincides with the result using GAP.